# NextJS javascript minification

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, minify

I have few scripts in public folder and added in _document.tsx like so

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import Script from 'next/script';

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <Script
          src="/js/jquery.min.js"
          strategy="beforeInteractive"
        ></Script>
        <Script src="/js/main.js" strategy="lazyOnload"></Script>
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

Problem is after npm run build scripts still unminified. How I can force NextJS minify them? I'm using latest(?) 12.2.2 version of NextJS.

Comment: Next.js minifies your `application code` on build, but not random scripts injected via `next/script` such as what you are doing here. You'd have to look into adding other entry points into your webpack configuration. You're probably barking up the wrong tree here... what's in `main.js` that you want to have a lazily loaded during idle? `next/script` is mostly for third party optional packages like chat boxes. Next already does a lot of optimization for core application code. Maybe you're looking for `next/dynamic` lazy library importing/components?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap theme, that's why. I know about dynamic importing and using it as well, thanks. My question is about custom added javascript minification in NextJS.

Comment: it will not minify random scripts imported via next/script. If you want to, you can add new entry points into your webpack config to have it bundle / minify your libs separately. Or set up your own separate webpack to manage your non next webpack code pipelines. Very non standard. Highly recommend using dynamic lib imports.

Comment: oh yeah, if you're using bootstrap, and the scripts are for bootstrap, then just download minified versions. Or point to remote minified CDN. There's no point minifying third party libs yourself :P